# How to layer images and create alpha transparency?

Tags: node-editor, image

I've created two node maps (or whatever they're called), one of which layers image textures on top of each other...
[image]

And another which allows the transparent parts of the images to be properly rendered...
[image]

But, when I try to combine the two, I notice something's missing.  Specifically, I don't know what to plug in to the "Fac" slot on the Mix Shader.
[image]

I've tried connecting everything from every other node, but it either screws up what I've already done (for example, certain textures disappearing) or does nothing.  I'm pretty new to this, so I have no idea what I should do.  In fact, the node maps were taken from some tutorials I found.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Good news!  I managed to figure it out.  I found this thread [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141701/overlay-more-than-one-transparent-images-in-one-shader), recreated the node map in the last picture on that thread, and lowered the emission strength so the villager wasn't blindingly bright.
[image]
Edit: Turns out replacing the Emission node with a Diffuse BSDF node works as well.  Good to know.